# How to use room entity (using a type converter) to parse Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, android-room, typeconverter

I have a entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @PrimaryKey
  private int uId;
  private String uName;
  private ArrayList<String> uPets = new ArrayList<>();

  public User() {}

  public User(int id, String name, List<String> pets){
    this.uId = id;
    this.uName = name;
    this.uPets.addAll(pets);
  };

  //getters setters removed for brevity
}
```

And the type converter is:

```
public class Converters {
  @TypeConverter
  public static ArrayList<String> fromString(String value) {
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
  }

  @TypeConverter
  public static String fromArrayLisr(ArrayList<String> list) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    return json;
  }
}
```

And the database class contains a line telling about the type converter:

```
@Database (entities = {User.class},version = 1)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class UserDB extends RoomDatabase {
  public abstract UserDAO userDAO();
}
```

So the above code all works fine in terms of storing the data to the database tables. However, I would now like to parse some JSON data representing the user data into `User` classes. The Json format looks like:

```
{ "uId": "123", 
  "uName": "John Doe",
  "uPets": [ "cat", "dog", "fish", "pizza"]
}
```

When I try to parse the above Json data using Gson it gives me an error that `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at path $.users[0].uPets`

I tried adding a type adapter to my GsonBuilder like:

`builder.registerTypeAdapter(ArrayList.class, new Converters())`

but that also gives me an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Preconditions.checkArgument($Gson$Preconditions.java:46)
        at com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(GsonBuilder.java:497)
...
```

any help appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you problem is that used ' in your uPets arrayList :

change ' to " in  'pizza"

'pizza"  -->  "pizza"

Comment: That was a typo sorry, I have corrected that in the OP now.